# PHP / Laravel: How to handle a SSE stream and parse fetched data

Tags: php, laravel, streaming, server-sent-events

I have a question. Has anyone dealt with a situation where you need to open a SSE (Server sent event) stream and parse the data with PHP (my case Laravel). My main goal is to save the incoming event to my database, but I don't seem to find a proper solution. I have tried to initiate a timeout and get the contents from the endpoint where the stream exists, but I don't see this as a proper solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is SSE specific to laravel? If not i'd suggest maybe just doing a php question with this protocol. So it can be debugged by you (in testing phases).

Comment: Well, I have mentioned laravel because maybe there is a low-rep package for this situation that you have ever used :) But in general, it is just a question for proper handling-scenarios that can help me achieve this goal.